# Ubuntu Server -Enviar correo con la info resultante de un comando

Tags: ubuntu, shell, shell-script

tengo este comando para ver el espacio de mi disco duro de mi server : `fdisk -l` y a eso le hago un grep para filtrar mas la info que me interesa (mi HD principal) :

El comando queda asi : `fdisk -l | grep vda`, y a esto le pongo el la cabecera de que es cada numero (el titulo) :  `df -h  | grep  -m1 "" &&  df -h | grep "/dev/vda1 "` , quedando de la siguiente manera ->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vale, una vez tengo la info que necesito, yo tengo un script para enviar correos, que funciona asi:

```
enviar_email.sh "(destinatario)" "Titutlo" "Cuerpo Mensaje"
```

Entonces, el **destinatario** y el **Titulo** estan cubiertos, pero el **cuerpo del mensaje** quiero enviar el output del comando anterior.

Lo que he intentado sin exito es :

```
./enviar_email correo_objetivo@gmail.com "Un Asunto" $(df -h  | grep  -m1 "" &&  df -h | grep "/dev/vda1 ")
```

Pero se envia el correo vacio a demas porque da error el comando que crea el cuerpo. Lo que estoy intentando es redirigir la salida al estilo : `echo "hola" > hola.txt` pero como parametro de mi script.

No se si es porque ese comando no da un output utilizable y si es asi no entiendo como podria capturarlo y enviarlo en un paso.

Y quiero evitar a toda costa tener que, previamente al script crear un fichero con el contenido del output del script y leerlo al enviar email, creo que es innecesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tratar de guardar la salida en una variable, de acuerdo a lo sugerido en [esta página](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/):

```
# Obtener salida en una variable
mensaje=$(df -h  | grep  -m1 "" &&  df -h | grep "/dev/vda1 ")
# Usar la variable como parámetro, anteponiendo $
./enviar_email "correo_objetivo@gmail.com" "Un Asunto" "$mensaje"
```